# Получить значение переменной из программы с помощью DLL

Tags: c++

У меня есть такая программа, она выступает в роли процесса в который инжектируется DLL:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
   int a = 5;
   std::cout << &a;
}
```

Мой DLL:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Определяет точку входа для приложения DLL.
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <iostream>

void DLLProject(PVOID)
{
    int p = 0x00F1F784;
    printf("%d", *(int*)p);
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        _beginthread(DLLProject, NULL, NULL);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Если я ввожу в DLL файл нужный адрес на котором находится переменная в программе, всё работает отлично, DLL выводит значение что там лежит.

Но как мне получить значение этой переменной если у меня есть исходный код программы и я не знаю её адрес?

Comment: В общем случае у переменной `a` может вообще не быть адреса. Компилятор может посчитать, что ее лучше разместить в регистре процессора или вообще заменить на константу.

Comment: в общем случае - никак. В скомпилированном коде нет имен "обычных переменных", более того, в указанном Вами примере компилятор может ещё и оптимизировать немного и выбросить много кода. Какую конкретно задачу решаете?

Comment: Недавно узнал что cs go написана практически полностью на C++(исходный код слит) и решил попробовать получить таким образом позиции игроков на карте. Но что то мне подсказывает, что это делается другими методами.

Comment: скорее всего там есть готовые функции, некое "апи"

Comment: Понял, буду искать другие способы.

Comment: Нашёл хорошую статью о том как перебирать адреса: https://habr.com/ru/post/93437/